# What does jarsigner verify in the first place (integrity or authenticity)?

Tags: authentication, android, digital-signature, integrity, code-signing

I was reading sth about android code signing and have run into this statement:

> The second `jarsigner` command at v in Listing 3-7 first verifies the
>   signature block and signing certificate, ensuring that the signature
>   file has not been tampered with. Next it verifies that each digest
>   in the signature file (CERT.SF ) matches its corresponding section in the
>   manifest file (MANIFEST.MF )...

We use code signing for both ensuring authenticity and integrity. In this particular case, it seems like we are trying to ensure the authenticity, not the integrity as the author put.

Or maybe I've interpreted this wrongly. Can you please explain if you think so?